# How to visualize angle of projection in Oblique Parallel Projection?

Tags: 3d, graphics, projection, projection-matrix, visualization

We know that in **Oblique Parallel Projection**  Point (x,y,z) is projected to position (x_p,y_p) on the view plane.Projector (oblique) from (x,y,z) to (x_p,y_p) makes an angle alpha.
with the line (L) on the projection plane that joins (x_p,y_p) and (x,y).
Line L is at an angle phi with the horizontal direction in the
projection plane.See this **image1**:
[image]

And in Oblique Parallel Projection Angles, distances, and parallel
lines in the plane are projected
accurately.For example see below **image2**:[image]

My question is where is the angle alpha in **image2**, I mean I see the angle phi on the image , so where is alpha in that image to understand better?I want to see 12 edges of original image projected to view plane with projector and angle alpha,phi levelling.

N. B:1 -- I am following [Hearn and Baker book which screenshot like this.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_nRZfRTqdkkKsQh2VrRvA-QAiQzeAIHx/view?usp=drivesdk)

N. B. -- I want to understand just intuition in easy way rather than details.

Comment: Alpha cannot be depicted on Image2, because it goes out of the plane.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross post of https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48585/how-to-visualize-angle-of-projection-in-oblique-parallel-projection

Comment: @Theraot could you provide the only the image "12 edges of original image projected to view plane with projector and angle alpha,phi levelling."

Comment: I'm convinced the best way to visualize this would be with 3D graphics. Which is entirely odd because we would be using a projection to understand another one. *I'll try to find if somebody has done it, I really don't want to program it.*

Comment: @Theraot I just want only the image.

Comment: Yes, but you have an image. I'm not sure the one you want will make the difference. Anyway, if I understand correctly, you want one like the one on Wikipedia (but with the angles labelled): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection#/media/File:Axonometric_projection.svg Let alone all the noise, how is the plane positioned in space there? (Orbiting around it would make it easy to grasp) - This is the best I have found so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWOMcGkHUIc - Keep in mind that alpha is between the segment that goes from a point to its projection, and the projection plane.

Comment: @Theraot could you label the image of wiki with angle alpha and phi?

Comment: I have the problem I described above. I don't know how the plane is positioned. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I hope this does it for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFMO5.png I created that with Sketchup and Gimp.

Comment: But I have one request, could you level all places where alpha and phi esixts?

Comment: Blue is alpha, green is phi; different views: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXQaC.png, 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cVvD.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxMse.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFaUb.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV5Bs.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzsR1.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUKR7.png

Comment: @Theraot Wow, Could you insert your comments in your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/198224/82314, https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/48585/7678.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OP request, I'm posting the images I produced as answer.

These were made with Sketchup. They show a cube a plane where the cube is projected in an oblique projection. The blue sectors represent the angle alpha, and green sectors represent the angle phi. Observe that the angle phi exists entirely in the projection plane, while alpha does not. Instead alpha is the angle between the projection plane and the segment that goes from a point to its projection. As a consequence it is impossible to depict alpha on the projection plane, since it goes out of it. Furthermore, depicting alpha requires knowing the relative position of the object and the projection plane.

*These images have perspective. It is odd to me that I'm using a projection to visualize another. However, I believe this is the best way to gain an intuition of it (actually I believe being able to orbit at will is better, but sans that here are multiple views).*

---

*I believe these are Cabinet, unless I'm confusing things.*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Animation*:

[image]

Comment: on 3rd image only phi angle but why alpha is absent?

Comment: @Ponting Alpha is on a plane you are looking on edge. Well, almost, due to the perspective, you can slightly see it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuDQl.png - Notice I only marked 4 of the 8 alpha, the other 4 are reduced to a line - But if I were using an orthographic projection, they would all be reduced to a line. By the same logic phi is not visible on the 6th picture.

Comment: one thing tell projection of cube you take front face of original image is perpendicular parallel projection on projection plane?

Comment: @Ponting Yes, I did project the closer face to the plane perpendicularly to it. Now I'm thinking I shouldn't have done that. I'll re do it (edit: I see, I made a cavalier projection, which is considered a type of oblique projection, but what we want in this case).

Comment: in Cabinet also front face is also perpendicular to projected image.

Comment: @Ponting Well, I'm projecting the same thing. However, it does not have to be perpendicular.

Comment: your cabinet become oblique due to absence of perpendicular.

Comment: @Ponting Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132128/discussion-between-theraot-and-ponting).

Comment: please check my image with alpha position is right or not? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a0ghThVkmhJb3z1w2pTqy5c1fzegmYMe/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Ponting I still think alpha cannot be depicted in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/waFgn.jpg. I don't know how to interpret what you did here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a0ghThVkmhJb3z1w2pTqy5c1fzegmYMe/view

Comment: how can visualize alpha and phi on this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/waFgn.jpg

Comment: it possible to see visualize alpha and phi on this https://i.stack.imgur.com/waFgn.jpg.please reply, I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: please help this question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/198583/is-diffuse-reflection-definition-failed-when-we-see-both-reflectiondiffuse-spec